# Match a line with a [ character, but don't match if it has a ] character

Tags: javascript, regex

I thought this regex would match lines with a `[`, but not if it has a `]`:

```
^.*\[.*(?!\]).*$
```

Instead, it's matching every line with a `[` (shown in **bold**):

> **This [should match]. This line should match**
>
> This line shouldn't match.
>
> **This line shouldn't match. This line [shouldn't match.**

How to fix that regex so that it doesn't match lines that have a `]`?

> **This [should match]. This line should match**
>
> This line shouldn't match.
>
> This line shouldn't match. This line [shouldn't match.

Demo: https://regexr.com/67qk7

Comment: Your expectations are contradicting the examples *"don't match if it has a ] character"* and then in the examples : `"This line [shouldn't match."`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"This regex would match lines with a ["* (one or more), *"but not if it has a ]"* (one or more):

```
^[^\][\n]*\[[^\]\n]*$
```

[image: Screenshot from Regex101]

Answer (score 4):

This pattern `^.*\[.*(?!\]).*$` matches `[` and the directly following `.*` will match the rest of the line.

Then at the end of the line it will assert not `]` directly to the right, which is true because it already is at the end of the line. Then the `.*` is optional and it can assert the end of the string.

So it will match any whole line that has at least a single `[`

If you want to match pairs of opening till closing square brackets `[...]` and not allow any brackets inside it, or single brackets outside of it and matching at least a single pair, you can repeat 1 or more times matching pairs surrounded by optional chars other than square brackets.

```
^(?:[^\][\n]*\[[^\][\n]*\])+[^\][\n]*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/szkXoD/1/)

Comment: This may not be easy to read due to escaped `[` and `\n` but is surely the most efficient regex for this problem

Comment: @anubhava I think in Javascript you have to escape the `\]` in a negated character class. Maybe I am wrong...

Comment: Yes that's right for JS

Answer (score 4):

An alternate solution which is not super efficient but is a bit shorter:

```sh
^(?!.*\[[^\]\n]*$)[^[\n]*\[.+$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iQ7tJK/1)

**Explanation:**

- `(?!.*\[[^\]\n]*$)` fails the match if we get a `[` without a closing `]` anywhere
- `[^[\n]*\[` matches first `[` in a line

Comment: Cool :-) that means not looking at an orphaned opening square bracket, thats clever.